# Signing a SOAP certificate in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, wsse

I'm working on signing some SOAP XML in Delphi 2010.

I've got most of it worked out (and I do have a .net working example)

I've got the c14n and digests all worked out 100%

I'm quite confident I'm doing the right thing with my signing certificate.

I just can't get the windows CryptoAPI to generate the actual rsa-sha1 signature.

For reasons to do with backward compatibiliity and support, I'm reluctant to use a .net or java solution.

What I'm looking for is one of:

- A working win32 example of xmldsig (using rsa/sha1) (any language)
- Delphi code to do same, using any mixture of readily available components
- A library I can use (must be royalty free and easy to distribute. Would prefer open source, but a commercial one would be acceptable if it works OK)
- Some hints on using the .net libraries from Delphi 2010
- Definitive confirmation that a later version of Delphi will handle signed soap.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean "signed soap", or do you really just need a client authentication certificate attached to the https message (containing the soap XML request)?

Comment: I really mean the soap header has to be digitally signed. The link has to use a client certificate too, but I've got that covered.